# Using Moonlight to connect to pc that it connected to wifi via usb tether to android phone

Tags: android, subnet, moonlight

So I have my desktop pc which is connected to the internet through usb tethering via my Galaxy s5. The s5 has given my pc an IPv4 address o 192.168.42.197 while my laptop im trying to use to connect to my pc is on a different subnet with the ip 192.168.1.4

I've been trying to use AFWall+ to change the iptables but have not had much success and was hoping someone with more experience in networking could be of some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i assume that your android is rooted,
and you trying to connect Laptop via Wifi.

then after connecting to pc via usb.
turn on hotspot on phone .
connect laptop to that hotspot.
and now open afwall+,
tick wifi and lan for  just DHCP+ DNS  service.
apply and enable firewall.
done...

there if another way if you have Lan Cable .
pc <==USB==>  Android.
and  connect pc and laptop directly with that cable.
now ,share internet connection of pc with laptop .

or

Laptop <==Wifi==> Android
and connect laptop with pc and on laptop  share internet connection with pc.

done...

**note:** please provide more info like routing table ,Gateway info,Operating Systems,ping status to help people provide exact answer...